# Stop StAX parser converting special characters in exported WebLogic JMS XML file

Tags: java, xml, weblogic-10.x, stax

I have a JMS queue file of messages in XML format, exported via WebLogic 11G.

In this file are various special characters, e.g. `&lt; &gt; &quot;`

I wrote a stAX parser to extract specific messages from this file, but as part of the parsing, the special characters are automatically converted (e.g. `&lt;` converted to `<`).

I need to import my cut-down XML file back into another JMS queue in WebLogic, but it won't import unless the special characters are in their original format.

Is there a way of doing this without having to manually convert them afterwards?

```
File inFile = new File(...);

XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
inputFactory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_COALESCING, true);

XMLEventReader eventReader = inputFactory.createXMLEventReader(new FileInputStream(inFile));

while (eventReader.hasNext()) {
    XMLEvent event = eventReader.nextEvent();

    if (event.isCharacters()) {
      System.out.println("Chars: " + event.asCharacters().getData());
    }
}
```

If one of the XML elements contains: `&quot;A bit of text&quot;` when I run in debug mode, the event/data has already been converted to `"A bit of text"`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

XML parsers will always "expand" built-in entity and character references in this way. When you're writing XML, you should use a library that does the inverse, i.e. turns special characters back into entity/character references.